# Needs a proof in a part of prime factorisation

Tags: math, proof, prime-factoring, number-theory

According to topcoder [Link](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=primeNumbers), We need to compute till square root of number to list its all prime factors... Now I am able to prove in the following code that we are doing right till we are in the for loop.. But I am unable to figure out  why the remaining number will be prime i.e. after we go out of the loop that if (n > 1) printf("%d",n); is what is troubling me ..! Can you please give me a formal proof along with  examples....

```
 void factor(int n) 
 { 
   int i; 
   for(i=2;i<=(int)sqrt(n);i++) 
   { 
     while(n % i == 0) 
     { 
       printf("%d ",i); 
       n /= i; 
     } 
   } 
   if (n > 1) printf("%d",n); 
   printf("\n"); 
 }
```

Comment: What exactly is the desired output? Should the output be `n` if `n` is prime and empty otherwise?

Comment: All the prime factors

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematical proof rather than programming.

Comment: Well it was realted to programming that is why I asked here because people might not understand  my doubt anywhere else

Comment: @Joe This is more about programming than about mathematical proof.  If it were solely about mathematical proof, we'd just loop until `i<=n` and wouldn't need to print the last factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially the process proceeds to search for the smallest factor of `n` smaller than its square root.
If it doesn't have one, then `n` is prime. So print out `n` as it's one smallest prime factor!

If you find a smallest factor then it must be prime. If not, it's composite and has a smaller prime factor - contradiction.

Having found the smallest prime factor divide n by that factor to eliminate it (remember it may be that `n == i*i*i*...i*r` where i is the prime factor and r the residue). That's what is happening inside the `while(n%i==0)` loop.

At the end of that we have `n` holding that residue.
So now we want the smallest prime factor of  r.
We know that smallest prime factor will be i. Why? Because if r had a smaller prime factor than i then i isn't the smallest prime factor of n.

So we can proceed to search i+1 to sqrt(r) by trial divisions of r to find the next smallest prime factor of n.
If we don't find any and r>1 then r is the last prime factor.

Proceed by induction.

After each round of elimination (go inside the `while(n%i==0)` loop) we have a number we know to have no prime factors <=i.

Answer (score 0):

Roughly speaking, for every factor `i` of `n` there is a cofactor `i'` such that `i*i'=n`, namely `n/i`. Without loss of generality assume`i=min{i,i'}`. Then `i<=sqrt(n)<=i'` holds. The implementation aims at finding `i` only while ignoring `i'`; the search space for `i` only is sufficient.

Each occurence of factor `i` is cancelled by the `n /= i` statement, which means that `n` is replaced by a factor of `i'`. Here two cases have to be considered. In the first case, this factor is prime, which means that no factors will be found in successive iterations. In the second case, the factor is composite; this means it has a factor smaller than `sqrt(i')<sqrt(n)`.

However, this factor must be larger than `i`, as all occurences of `i` have been eliminated by the `while` loop. This means that a remaining factor lies between `i+1` and `sqrt(n)`, which will be found in successive iterations.

Comment: So even if there is a prime factor greater than square root of number .. This approach will miss it?? I think that last if statement is for this case only... And as I guess topcoder guys wont be wrong...I think that will print a prime !!